# how to Setup Grub Password ONLY to access grub menu?

Tags: boot, grub2, password, authentication

Need help to configure Grub Password only for accessing Grub Menu. I DO NOT want to enter user name and password at the time of each reboot.

I've configured Grub User ID and Password by following [this link](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-password-protect-the-grub-boot-loader-in-ubuntu/) and it works as expected, only challenge is, that I have to enter the password at every reboot & I don't want to do that.

Also, I did try reading through this [Ubuntu document](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords) as I think it has a solution to what I'm looking for but unfortunately I find it too tough to understand.

Can this be done in 20.04 LTS on which I'm trying to set that up? So please help guys!

Thanks in advance! Stay safe! :)

Answer (score 1):

For the password by default everywhere , you can create a file `/etc/grub.d/00_before_header`

The name `00_before_header` is important  , because it will before `00_header`in the alphabetic order .

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
cat <<EOF
set superusers="admin"
password admin password
export superusers    
EOF
```

and you must run `chmod +x /etc/grub.d/00_before_header`

This following patch will modify option named `Ubuntu` to have no password .

- will modify `/etc/grub.d/10_linux`
- run upgrade-grub
- check that you have a menuentry with the option `--unrestricted` in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

The patch for **/etc/grub.d/10_linux** :

```
--- 10_linux.orig   2020-05-16 05:26:00.107936462 +0000
+++ 10_linux    2020-05-16 05:26:40.040071516 +0000
@@ -190,7 +190,12 @@
       fi
       echo "menuentry '$(echo "$title" | grub_quote)' ${CLASS} \$menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-$version-$type-$boot_device_id' {" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
   else
+      OLD_CLASS="$CLASS" 
+      if [ "$(echo "$os" | grub_quote)" = "Ubuntu" ]; then
+          CLASS="$CLASS  --unrestricted" 
+      fi
       echo "menuentry '$(echo "$os" | grub_quote)' ${CLASS} \$menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-$boot_device_id' {" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
+      CLASS="$OLD_CLASS" 
   fi      
   if [ "$quick_boot" = 1 ]; then
       echo "   recordfail" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
```

**PS:** this solution is for Ubuntu 20.04

**PS2:** patch => https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_%28Unix%29

**PS3:** patch format => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987372/what-is-the-format-of-a-patch-file

Comment: Just a question I copied and pasted the part you gave into "/etc/grub.d/10_linux" and not sure in that where am I suppose to update the password hash? can you please elaborate that part for me?

Comment: @Hrish for the password this the first part but you did already that

Comment: hey thanks for reply. So do you want me to update that last patch in /boot/grub/grub.cfg / or / /etc/grub.d/10_linux or /etc/grub.d/00_before_header? and where in the file like in the beginning or ending? Also what are "---", "@@" & "+" these signs are for? Am I suppose to copy & Paste that patch with all those signs?

Comment: i updated my response with some links to the patch command